# Trying to determine physically meaningful initial conditions for test particle around a Kerr black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, computational-physics, simulations, kerr-metric

I am working on some code for a test particle orbiting a Kerr black hole.  I am trying to determine what the initial $ \frac{d t}{d\tau} $ would be.  On Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric, it says that the time dilation equation is $ \frac{t}{\tau}=\sqrt{\frac{(a^2+r^2 )^2-a^2\Delta sin^2\theta}{\Delta\Sigma}} $ where $ \Delta=r^2-r_sr+a^2 $, $ r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2} $, $ \Sigma=r^2+a^2cos^2\theta $, $ a=\frac{J}{Mc} $, $ r $ is the distance from the black hole center of mass, $ M $ is the mass of the black hole and $ J $ is the angular momentum of the black hole.  The test particle is time-like and the coordinates are Boyer-Lindquist coordinates.  I know that $ p_t=const. $ and 
$ p_{\phi}=const. $, but what should I choose for the initial condition $ \frac{dt}{d\tau} $?  This might be obvious, but it isn't to me.  Please help if you know what I should do!  Thank you!

Comment: $dt/d\tau=\sqrt{g^{tt}} / \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ where $v$ is the local velocity relative to a ZAMO, see http://kerr.newman.yukterez.net

Comment: Thank you, Yukterez ! That really helps!